# Using pandas dictionary for creating sql tables

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dictionary

I would like to use my pandas dictionary in order to create sql tables. My dictionary looks like this:

```
my_dict -> {'ETL_A': ['TABLE_001', 'TABLE_002', 'TABLE_003'],
            'TEST': ['TABLE_TEST', 'TEST001', 'SAMPLE_TEST'],
            'MY_PRIVATE_SHEMA': ['WWW_001', 'LTT_222']}
```

In this dictionary my shema names are keys...ETL_A,TEST,MY_PRIVATE_SHEMA with list of tables. I would need to create sql inserts:

```
string = 'CREATE TABLE {SCHEMA}.TABLE_NAME SELECT * FROM {SCHEMA}.TABLE_NAME at(timestamp => {TIMESTAMP}::timestamp);'.format(SCHEMA=SCHEMA, TIMESTAMP=TIMESTAMP)
```

I'm using variables SCHEMA and TIMESTAMP. Example SCHEMA = 'TEST' and TIMESTAMP = '10-06-26 02:31:29'. I would like to base don my key in the dictionary so in my case shema name , create sql ddl commands. So if I need to create tables in the TEST shema my code would give me an output:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST.TABLE_TEST SELECT * FROM TEST.TABLE_TEST at(timestamp => '10-06-26 02:31:29'::timestamp);
CREATE TABLE TEST.TEST001 SELECT * FROM TEST.TEST001 at(timestamp => '10-06-26 02:31:29'::timestamp);
CREATE TABLE TEST.SAMPLE_TEST SELECT * FROM TEST.SAMPLE_TEST at(timestamp => '10-06-26 02:31:29'::timestamp);
```

So based on my key(schema name) I would get all tables from that shema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly, you almost have a solution -- you just need to iterate through your dictionary, and plug the values in the string.

```py
from datetime import datetime

for schema, tables in my_dict.items():
    for table in tables:
        timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        print(f"CREATE TABLE {schema}.{table} SELECT * FROM {schema}.{table} at(timestamp => '{timestamp}'::timestamp);")
```

Which for `my_dict` from the question outputs the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ETL_A.TABLE_001 SELECT * FROM ETL_A.TABLE_001 at(timestamp => '2022-10-04 19:31:25'::timestamp);
CREATE TABLE ETL_A.TABLE_002 SELECT * FROM ETL_A.TABLE_002 at(timestamp => '2022-10-04 19:31:25'::timestamp);
CREATE TABLE ETL_A.TABLE_003 SELECT * FROM ETL_A.TABLE_003 at(timestamp => '2022-10-04 19:31:25'::timestamp);
CREATE TABLE TEST.TABLE_TEST SELECT * FROM TEST.TABLE_TEST at(timestamp => '2022-10-04 19:31:25'::timestamp);
CREATE TABLE TEST.TEST001 SELECT * FROM TEST.TEST001 at(timestamp => '2022-10-04 19:31:25'::timestamp);
CREATE TABLE TEST.SAMPLE_TEST SELECT * FROM TEST.SAMPLE_TEST at(timestamp => '2022-10-04 19:31:25'::timestamp);
CREATE TABLE MY_PRIVATE_SHEMA.WWW_001 SELECT * FROM MY_PRIVATE_SHEMA.WWW_001 at(timestamp => '2022-10-04 19:31:25'::timestamp);
CREATE TABLE MY_PRIVATE_SHEMA.LTT_222 SELECT * FROM MY_PRIVATE_SHEMA.LTT_222 at(timestamp => '2022-10-04 19:31:25'::timestamp);
```

I use an f-string rather than the `.format(...)` formatting, but it is very similar: instead the `f` in the front, you could equivalently also write `.format(schema=schema, table=table, timestamp=timestamp)` at the end.

Comment: Thank you for your solution but I would need something per shema. I would need to create tables per shema, so selecting one shema and get all tables from this shema. If I need shema TEST I would create variable shema='TEST' and some specific timestamp so variable timestamp = '2022-01-01 00:00:00'.

Comment: I don't understand. Could you write an example how the solution should look like? Is the sql query in your question not the desired output?

Comment: I would first define shema as shema=test and use this im order to her obły this shema and tables.

Comment: Could you please explicitly spell out the desired output for the example in your question?

Comment: I will use this:
timestamp = '2022-01-01 00:00:00'
sf_schema = 'TEST'
for schema, tables in my_dict.items():
    for table in tables:
        if schema == sf_schema:
            print(f"CREATE TABLE {schema}.{table} SELECT * FROM {schema}.{table} at(timestamp => '{timestamp}'::timestamp);")

Comment: Alright, glad to hear it works for you now :)